# SetAuthCookie - If I set createPersistentCookie to "false," shouldn't I have to log in again after closing browser?

Tags: forms, authentication, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 application using forms authentication, and I am trying to figure out why, even after setting the 'createPersistentCookie' parameter to false, I am able to close the browser, open it back up, and go right into my website without having to log in again?

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, "false");
```

My understanding is that by setting that to "false," it should force the user to login in after closing and re-opening their browser, correct?

I am having a hard time understanding the interplay between that persistent cookie setting in the "SetAuthCookie" method and the timeout setting in the web config. Seems to me if I set the timeout in the web config to 1440 (minutes), the persist cookie setting seems to make no difference one way or another. I've read a bunch of other threads on this, but am still confused.

What I would like is, if the user does NOT check the "Remember Me" box (persist cookie should be false), then when they close the browser or go for like 30 minutes without activity, they should have to log back in again. If they DO check it, then they shouldn't have to log in again for the time period specified in the web config. Will I have to add code myself to do this where I am setting the auth cookie?